# Why does Internet Explorer make content inside a div with overflow:hidden disappear?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The contents inside the inner-most div show up on every browser except for IE. Why? I've noticed that if I remove `overflow:hidden` from `.absolute_container`, then the contents inside `.item` will show up, but I need `overflow:hidden`` to remain for display reasons.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="absolute">
                <div class="absolute_container">
                    <div class="relative">
                        <div class="item_wrap">
                            <div class="item">
                                // doesn't show up in IE
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.absolute_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item_wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 16px;
    font-size: 12px;
    clear: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.item {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Even though I already know the answer you're going to give to this question, I still have to ask - are all of those divs really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your float on `.item` to put it back into that layout, otherwise the parent element has no idea how big the element is, which is why it disappears when using `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that doesn't work. The content is still invisibile in IE, but visible in all other browsers.