# Why does my div disappear in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Internet Explorer make content inside a div with overflow:hidden disappear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690700/why-does-internet-explorer-make-content-inside-a-div-with-overflowhidden-disapp)

The contents inside `<div class="item">` disappear in Internet Explorer, but are visible in all other browsers. Why? This question is a modified version of a previous question that never received an answer. Maybe my modifications have led me closer to a possible solution?

HTML:

```
<td class="table_class">
    <div class="relative">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="absolute">
                <div class="item_container">
                    <div class="item">
                        // there may be several of these divs
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.table_class {
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0;
}

.relative {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item_container {
    height: 16px;
    font-size: 12px;
    clear: both;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.item {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

What am I missing? (yes, the two divs with class="relative" are needed).

Comment: **Quote:**  _"yes, the two divs with class='relative' are needed"_  ~ I seriously doubt it.  Why so many redundantly nested `div`'s? and why are these `div`'s inside of `td`?  This is all very bad practice.  If you understand how to use a `div`, then you wouldn't need the `table`.

Comment: Then I guess Google Calendar is "very bad practice"?

Comment: If their code looks like that, then yes.  If you want help, please explain what you're trying to achieve and what you've already tried.

Comment: BECAUSE IT IS INTERNET EXPLORER! (NOT USING CAPSLOCK EITHER)

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding `width` and `height` to the `.absolute` CSS class.

Also why does your `.item` class have both `float: left;` and `clear: both;`?

I would suggest removing the `clear: both` attribute and instead add a sibling `div` to to your `item` div and add the style `clear: both` to it as follows:

```
<div class="item_container">
    <div class="item">
        // there may be several of these divs
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

If this doesn't work try adding `width` and `height` to the `.item` class as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try using your ``clear`` suggestion. I can't set the width and height, because I'm using a fluid layout. Maybe I could use jquery, but I don't want to cheat.

Comment: @AaronBrokmeier Lol! When supporting Internet Explorer developers are almost *always* forced to cheat. :P